# Using Regex to extract the last date in a series

Tags: regex, excel

So I have a series of dates given to me in a single go. For example:

```
June 8th, 11th, 15th, 16th, 18th, 23rd
```

Yay, poorly formatted data.

Anyways, I managed to write a regex to parse out the first date -

```
(?:jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)[A-Z]*\s[0-9]{1,2}
```

So in order to extract the last number, I used the following:

```
=RevStr(regex(RevStr(TextInQuestion),"[0-9]{1,2}"))
```

Where RevStr reverses the string, and regex extracts the given pattern.

I feel there has to be a better way - is there?

Comment: I'm not sure if negative lookaheads are supported in Excel, but the RegEx pattern to match the last one or two digits is: `\d{1,2}(?!.*\d{1,2})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex:

```
(?:jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)[A-Z]*(?:,*\s([0-9]{1,2})[a-z]{2})*
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eRwhsN/2)